AWS API gateway won't save settings on 'Enable Cors' on my resource
Proof is in this screenrecording https://www.loom.com/share/5225e46c060a4357ad39531372fe0c8e?sid=6e42106c-35fe-4937-a1eb-b073fb87e3f4
I have enabled/ensured Access-Control-Allow-Origin , Access-Control-Allow-Methods , Access-Control-Allow-Headers and appropriate values like '*' and 'POST,OPTIONS' in both the intergration response and method response in both my OPTIONS and POST methods (the only methods I have right now).
Then made sure to deploy but I still get this when posting from axios from localhost:3000 in my react frontend :
XMLHttpRequest at 'https://[api-gateway-id].execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/Dev' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
However when I POST with curl from terminal with -H "Content-Type: application/json" I get :
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   157  100    53  100   104    143    281 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   424{"statusCode": 200, "body": ""Hello from Lambda!""}
Showing my endpoint url is correct and there is a connection

Looks like a bug. I would contact the AWS support.

Try setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to a real domain instead of * (wildcard).  With CORS you can't mix wildcard origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials.  Some things to keep in mind: I see the error is on the Preflight response, which means its the Options method that is failing).  Posting from a terminal works because the terminal isn't enforcing CORS, but the browser does.

I am developing on local host on my PC so will I need to deploy my dev on to a sever ? Struggling to think of what domain I should set it to or would http://localhost:3000 work ?

How are you going to set anything if the settings aren't saved?
